# Last quarter of the hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I found the following

```
Select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0)
```

which is great for rounding to the last quarter of the hour. But I would like to always get the last quarter of the last hour.

e.g.,

If time is 12:35 am I want to see 11:45 am since that is the last quarter of the hour.

Comment: Have you tried subtracting one hour using the same dateadd function?

Comment: So, if the current time is within the last quarter of the hour, you want to get the current hour, and if it's before that, you want the previous hour, is that correct?

Comment: Have a look into the link https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23840058/SQL-Server-round-date-to-last-quarter-of-an-hour.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetimefromparts()`:

```
select datetimefromparts(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), datepart(hour, dt), 45, 0, 0)
from (values (dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()))) v(dt);
```

Comment: Perfect!  I learned about "datetimefromparts" and I learned a new word "succinct"; thanks Larnu.   Nice way to start the day.  But seriously thank you for the kick in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long winded, just the way my mind works (Gordan's is far more succinct that mine):

```
DECLARE @time time = '12:35'

SELECT CONVERT(time,DATEADD(MINUTE,45,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,'00:00',DATEADD(MINUTE, -45, @time)),'00:00')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question, you want to get the current hour of the current minute is between 45 and 59, or the previous hour if the current minute is between 0 and 44 - So here is my suggested solution:

```
DECLARE @ActualTime DateTime = GetDate()

SELECT @ActualTime As ActualTime, DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Now), MONTH(Now), DAY(Now), DATEPART(HOUR, Now), 45, 0, 0) As LastQuarterOfHour
FROM 
(
    SELECT IIF(DATEPART(MINUTE,@ActualTime) < 45, DATEADD(HOUR, -1, @ActualTime), @ActualTime) As Now
) AS x
```